# Omniscript, Select Custom option source, Apex class

Tags: apex, custom, selectoption, omniscript

I want to use Apex class to get options in my select element.

In select property I set 'Oprion source' to Custom and 'Source' to class.method, but it does not work. My select is empty. Activate omniscript does not help.

My Apex class:

```
global class SelectOptions implements vlocity_ins.VlocityOpenInterface{



public Boolean invokeMethod(String methodName,
                           Map<String, Object> input,
                           Map<String, Object> outMap,
                           Map<String, Object> options){
    
    if(methodName.equals('Type'))
    {
        List<Map<String, String>> UIoptions = new List<Map<String, String>>();
        
   
         Map <String, String> tempMap = new Map <String, String>();
         tempMap.put('name', 'Type1');
         tempMap.put('value', 'type1');
            
         UIoptions.add(tempMap);
        
        outMap.put('options', UIoptions);
        
        System.debug(outMap);
        System.debug(UIoptions);
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Select properties:
[image]

Has anyone had a similar problem? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Please add Callable in interface. global class SelectOptions implements vlocity_ins.VlocityOpenInterface, Callable{